# How to specify log file different from daemon log file while submitting a flink job in a standalone flink cluster

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

When I am starting a flink standalone cluster, It logs daemon logs in a file mentioned in conf/log4j.properties file, and when I submit a flink job in that cluster, it uses same properties file to log the application logs and write into same log file on taskmanagers. I want to have separate log files for my each application submitted in that flink standalone cluster. Is there any way to achieve that

Answer (score 3):

When you submit the job using the ./bin/flink shell script, use the following environment variables to control log file location:

- FLINK_LOG_DIR specifies the directory where the log will appear
- FLINK_IDENT_STRING allows you to make the filename unique

For example if you start your job with

```
FLINK_LOG_DIR=/var/log FLINK_IDENT_STRING=my_app_id ./bin/flink run /path/to/the.jar
```

then the logs will appear in /var/log/flink-my_app_id-client-$HOSTNAME.log

Note that this only applies to the messages that are logged via the logging frameworks and not for the things that are just printed to stdout.

Comment: This will cater only logs at client side not for the application running into cluster. Any other solution please.

Comment: For me, when using the local flink cluster, it creates the correct logfiles, and writes some messages to it, however most of the messages are still written to the default log, so all jobs still go to the default log. I don't know why this happens, because my logback.xml contains a logger for `de.mydomain.myapp`, and `de.mydomain.myapp.something` goes to the separate log, but `de.mydomain.myapp.somethingelse` goes to the default log.