# Flink: how to have separate log files and logging configuration for different jobs on the same TaskManager?

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

I run multiple job on the same TaskManager on a single machine. Both of them write to the same TaskManager's and JobManager's log and .out files.

**Is there any way to separate the log files of these jobs into separate files with different logging configs for each job?**

Is that solution also applied to Flink in standalone cluster mode?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to specify log file different from daemon log file while submitting a flink job in a standalone flink cluster](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40487401/how-to-specify-log-file-different-from-daemon-log-file-while-submitting-a-flink)

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know this is not possible. The reason is that when you make a call to the LOGGER, it would be quite hard for the framework to figure out from which job instance you are calling it.

The only way around it is to have one task manager per job, but it comes with a big overhead.